# When using LIBADD in automake, libtool links incorrectly

Tags: c, autoconf, automake, libtool

I'm using automake to build my project. I have some third-party (open source) libraries as git submodules in my project that I want to individually build and link. Here's an edited (names changed) version of my Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la libbar.la
libbar_la_SOURCES = ../submodules/bar/bar.c

libfoo_la_LIBADD = libbar.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
    some_source.c \
    some_other_source.c

libfoo_la_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = $(LIBS)

if OS_LINUX
libfoo_la_SOURCES += \
    linux/some_source.c \
    linux/some_other_source.c

libfoo_la_CFLAGS += $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS)
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS += $(PTHREAD_LIBS)
endif

if OS_WINDOWS_MSYS
libfoo_la_SOURCES += \
    nt/some_source.c \
    nt/some_other_source.c

libfoo_la_LDFLAGS += -no-undefined
endif

bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c
main_LDADD = libfoo.la
```

`autoreconf`, `configure` and `make` run normally but `make install` fails with

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbar
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems autoconf is trying to use `libbar` as a global, installed library instead of a local one? `LDADD` on the `main` target works fine though.

`autoreconf -V` outputs

```
autoreconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.71
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <https://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

EDIT: I am on Linux. Don't mind the windows parts.

Comment: Did you just forget to copy the `libbar_la_LDFLAGS += -no-undefined` line to the above example, or is that missing in your actual code as well?

Comment: @ndim I forgot to mention, this issue is on Linux, I haven't even tried on Windows. Linux does not need -no-undefined.

Comment: What Linux distribution, autoconf, automake, libtool versions? What actual linker command, what actual make output? Does https://github.com/ndim/stackoverflow-q70584133 work for you or fail as well?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce this on https://github.com/ndim/stackoverflow-q70584133 by basically copying the `Makefile.am` you have given and adding a few very basic source files.

I found that building on Linux for Linux (Fedora 35, autoconf 2.69-37, automake 1.16.2-5, libtool 2.4.6-42) worked fine. Also running the `make install`ed result:

```
[user@host stackoverflow-q70584133]$ mkdir _b-host && cd _b-host
[user@host _b-host]$ ../configure --prefix=$PWD/_i
[user@host _b-host]$ make && make install && ./_i/bin/main
[...]
main: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
foo_func
bar_func
foo_host_func: Linux 331524 = 0x50f04 = 5.15.4 (5.15.4)
[user@host _b-host]$ _
```

So if you have problems building on and for Linux, something else must be off.

I presume you have run `make distclean` and then re-run `autoreconf` and `configure` to make sure your buildsystem and source tree and build tree are in a well defined state.

However, building on Fedora 35 for Windows (both 32 and 64bit) failed for me when building `libbar.la` **without `-no-undefined`**:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -g -O2   -o libbar.la -rpath /home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-w32/_i/lib ../bar/libbar_la-bar.lo  
libtool: warning: undefined symbols not allowed in i686-w64-mingw32 shared libraries; building static only
libtool: link: i686-w64-mingw32-ar cru .libs/libbar.a  ../bar/libbar_la-bar.o
libtool: link: i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib .libs/libbar.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libbar.la" && ln -s "../libbar.la" "libbar.la" )
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -g -O2 -no-undefined  -o libfoo.la -rpath /home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-w32/_i/lib foo/libfoo_la-foo.lo  foo/libfoo_la-foo-nt.lo libbar.la  

*** Warning: This system cannot link to static lib archive libbar.la.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.
libtool: link: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared  foo/.libs/libfoo_la-foo.o foo/.libs/libfoo_la-foo-nt.o    -g -O2   -o .libs/libfoo-0.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libfoo.dll.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/11.2.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: foo/.libs/libfoo_la-foo.o: in function `foo_func':
/home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-w32/src/../../src/foo/foo.c:10: undefined reference to `bar_func'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:521: libfoo.la] Error 1
```

Adding a line to `Makefile.am` like

```
libbar_la_LDFLAGS += -no-undefined
```

fixed the linking for Windows problem and made the whole thing build and run (built on Linux, run on Linux using wine):

```
[user@host stackoverflow-q70584133]$ mkdir _b-w64 && cd _b-w64
[user@host _b-w64]$ ../configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=$PWD/_i
[user@host _b-w64]$ make && make install && ./_i/bin/main.exe
[...]
main: x86_64-w64-mingw32
foo_func
bar_func
foo_host_func: Windows 0x0a00 = 10.0
[user@host _b-w64]$ _
```

(And BTW, `LIBS` and `_LIBS` type variables should probably be added to a `_LIBADD` or `_LDADD` variable, not to a `_LDFLAGS` variable.)

**UPDATE**

Building on Debian 10 (autoconf 2.69-11, automake 1:1.16.1-4, libtool 2.4.6-9), does produce a linker error when `main_LDADD` is missing `libbar.la` and `src/main.c` calls the `bar_func()` function from `libbar` (uncomment the `#define` in src/main.c to reproduce):

```
[user@host _b-host]$ make
[...]
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o main main-main.o libfoo.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/main main-main.o  ./.libs/libfoo.so -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-host/_i/lib
/usr/bin/ld: main-main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'bar_func'
/usr/bin/ld: //home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-host/src/.libs/libbar.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:525: main] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/stackoverflow-q70584133/_b-host/src'
make: *** [Makefile:390: all-recursive] Error 1
[user@host _b-host]$ _
```

However, after removing the direct calls to `libbar`'s `bar_func()` from `src/main.c`, the `make` command will work again, as does `make install`:

```
[user@host _b-host]$ make install && ./_i/bin/main
main: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
foo_func
bar_func
foo_host_func: Linux 267216 = 0x413d0 = 4.19.208
[user@host _b-host]$ _
```

This suggests that calling a function from `libbar` from a linking unit without explicitly linking that unit against `libbar` is an error, and that does make sense.

So I still cannot reproduce OP's report of `make` working but `make install` failing. OP is using newer autoconf (2.71) than I do (2.69). Perhaps OP is using different automake/libtool versions as well with different set of bugs (`dpkg -l autoconf automake libtool`, `rpm -q autoconf automake libtool`, etc.)?

Comment: Good investigation. I've always had a love/hate relationship with autotools I love it when it works and I hate it when it doesn't. It worked flawlessly building KDE3 from start to finish during the old Pentium days (7 hour build with koffice included). But I've also had fits sorting out problems. Like anything else, you have to pay the price to make friends with it if you use it regularly.